My sitecore Marketing automation service in not running in my local which is causing issue in EXM
My Sitecore Marketing automation service in not running in local.
Getting 1064 error: an exception occurred in the service while handling the control request.

How to fix it?
I have checked the event viewer i am getting below error.
The Elo103SitecoreMarketingAutomationEngine service terminated with the following error: 
An exception occurred in the service when handling the control request.

I have also tried to give different roles access to it but no luck.

Did you also tried running the certificate command as well?

You can check following steps to start Marketing automation Service.

Make sure the license is valid.

Run the below command from Powershell to check for Non-self-signed certificates.


Get-Childitem cert:\LocalMachine\root -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Issuer -ne $_.Subject}

If above command returns certificate run below command to move these certificates into Intermediate Certification Authorities.
Get-Childitem cert:\LocalMachine\root -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Issuer -ne $_.Subject} | Move-Item -Destination Cert:\LocalMachine\CA


Make sure XConnect certificate have following app roles added to it.


IUSR
Network Service
Service
IIS_IUSRS
Service Account

Once all these changes are there, you can try starting Marketing Automation Service.
Hope this helps!!!
